# Open camera in "Photo Sphere" or "Panoramic" mode

Tags: android, camera, panoramas

Hello I'm trying to open the camera in panoramic mode but I can not clear it.
Searching I found this:

> [Use PanoramaApi with custom equirectangular image from Assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34991105/use-panoramaapi-with-custom-equirectangular-image-from-assets-folder)

But this post opens a photo in panoramic mode and does not open the camera

This other link:

> [How to open camera directly in panorama/photosphere mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377663/how-to-open-camera-directly-in-panorama-photosphere-mode)

It do not recognize many of the parameters of the activity defined in the Manifest

And I have not found anything else

Comment: Not all camera apps have a "panoramic mode". Not all devices will have a camera app with a "panoramic mode". And any such mode is proprietary to that app and is not necessarily available to third-party app developers, such as yourself.

Comment: Try this: Intent intent = new Intent (MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);
startActivity(intent);